# Error 1005(105) can't create table... but why?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

```
create table bankdb.customer(
    customer_name varchar(45) not null,
    social_security int not null,
    customer_street varchar(45),
    customer_city varchar(45),
primary key(`social_security`)
)engine=InnoDB;

create table bankdb.branch(
    branch_name varchar(45) not null,
    branch_city varchar(45),
    assets int,
primary key (`branch_name`)
)engine=InnoDB;

create table bankdb.account(
    branch_name varchar(45),
    account_number varchar(45) not null,
    balance int,
primary key (`account_number`),
constraint fk_acount_branch
    foreign key (`branch_name`)
    references bankdb.branch(`branch_name`)
)engine=InnoDB;  

create table bankdb.depositor(
    customer_name varchar(45) not null,
    account_number varchar(45) not null,
primary key (`customer_name`, `account_number`),
constraint fk_depositor_customer
    foreign key(`customer_name`)
    references bankdb.customer(`customer_name`),
constraint fk_depositor_account
    foreign key(`account_number`)
    references bankdb.account(`account_number`)
)engine=InnoDB;
```

That's my sql code... i get the error can't create table for the table bankdb.depositor... Is there anything wrong with my foreign keys? Any clues?

Comment: I ran into hte same issue. I know if you remove engine=InnoDB it works but not really the root cause

Comment: i added engine=InnoDB after the error trying to fix it but nothing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, based on your new script the following appears to be working in SQL Fiddle.  I had to add indexes:

```
create table bankdb.customer(
    customer_name varchar(45) not null,
    social_security int not null,
    customer_street varchar(45),
    customer_city varchar(45),
  primary key(`social_security`),
  INDEX (customer_name)
)engine=InnoDB;

create table bankdb.branch(
    branch_name varchar(45) not null,
    branch_city varchar(45),
    assets int,
  primary key (`branch_name`)
)engine=InnoDB;

create table bankdb.account(
    branch_name varchar(45),
    account_number varchar(45) not null,
    balance int,
  primary key (`account_number`),
  INDEX (account_number),
  constraint fk_acount_branch
      foreign key (`branch_name`)
      references bankdb.branch(`branch_name`)
)engine=InnoDB;  

create table bankdb.depositor(
  customer_name varchar(45) not null,
  account_number varchar(45) not null,
  primary key (`customer_name`, `account_number`),
  INDEX (customer_name),  
  INDEX (account_number),
  constraint fk_depositor_customer
      foreign key(`customer_name`)
      references bankdb.customer(`customer_name`),
  constraint fk_depositor_account
      foreign key(`account_number`)
      references bankdb.account(`account_number`)
)engine=InnoDB;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a731c)

<strike>If this is your full script your issue is with the create table for `account`.</strike>

You are trying to create a foreign key on the `branch` table which doesn't appear to exist:

```
create table bankdb.account(
    branch_name varchar(45),
    account_number varchar(45) not null,
    balance int,
primary key (`account_number`),
constraint fk_acount_branch
    foreign key (`branch_name`)
    references bankdb.branch(`branch_name`)  -- does this exist
)engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: sorry my bad... deleted wrong table from my post... 
create table bankdb.branch(
 branch_name varchar(45) not null,
 branch_city varchar(45),
 assets int,
primary key (`branch_name`)
)engine=InnoDB;

Comment: thanks a lot... i had totally not understood the indexes... so that i know.. you index everything you use in foreign keys or just the ones that are not set as primary keys in the reference table?

Comment: @GeorgeF-bot yes you should be indexing those columns. :)